# Why is my Vagrant bootstrap file not modifying bash_login?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, bash

When I SSH into my Vagrant box, I would like it to run the following two commands;

```
cd /vagrant
git status
```

So naturally I would modify my ~/.bash_login to do this

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_login
cd /vagrant
git status
EOF
```

If I then exit, and ssh back into my box - it works!

So then I added those exact commands to my bootstap.sh provisioning file, so that each time my box is provisioned, it would add it automatically to my bash_login script.

Except it doesnt work. The output during provisioning shows it including the two commands, but when I then SSH into the box nothing happens. If I view my bash_login file - the changes are not there?

Any ideas why not? I'm wondering if perhaps when I SSH into the box, I am a different user than when the box is being provisioned, so when I edit the  bash_login script I am editting another user's file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I worked it out. In case anyone comes across this same issue - I was editting the wrong bash file. This works;

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /home/vagrant/.bashrc
cd /vagrant
git status
EOF
```

Comment: The vagrant bootstrap files are run as root so `~`refers to `/root` unless you `su vagrant` or use absolute paths as suggested by your answer.