# Vagrant provisioning succeeds, but ssh does not contain dirs, env variables, etc

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

I have a vagrant provisioning script which succeeds -- I can see the output from the logs and my dependencies are being installed, my directories and files are being created and copied over, etc. but **when I `vagrant ssh` into the VM none of the folders, files, env variables, and installations are there**.

*Edit: `git`, `curl`, etc. work, but `gvm`, `go`, and `$GOPATH` etc do not, and my `go` directory does not exist*

**I'm confident the provisioning works correctly because I can run my web server from the script** and confirm the application is being served.

Is this just the way Vagrant is set up? What's the point of `vagrant ssh` if so?

I'm running the default "hashicorp/precise32" box, Ubuntu 12.04, default provider.

**Shell script**

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Provisioning virtual machine"
sudo apt-get update


echo "Installing Dependencies"
# Base dependencies: curl git
# Dependencies for gvm: make bison
sudo apt-get install curl git make bison -y 2> /dev/null

# Dependencies for add-apt-repository: python-software-properties software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common -y 2> /dev/null

# This allows us to get an updated version of git, which we need for gvm
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y 2> /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y 2> /dev/null


echo "Installing GVM"
bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)
source ~/.gvm/scripts/gvm


echo "Installing and configuring Go"
gvm install go1.4
gvm use go1.4 --default
mkdir -p ~/go/{bin,pkg,src}
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin


echo "Installing Nginx"
sudo apt-get install nginx -y 2> /dev/null
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
`# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "init.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4000, guest: 8080
end`
```

Comment: Could you please provide the _Vagrantfile_ file?

Comment: Just added it to the original post

Comment: Trying some diff combos -- if I `cd ~` none of the dirs I create show up ... possible that `~` refers to somewhere other than my home during provisioning?

Answer (score 1):

The Vagrant provisioning script is running as root, so `~` refers to `/root` instead of `/home/vagrant`.

Options to resolve are `su -c "*your command*" vagrant` or using absolute paths, which is probably the best approach.

Similar issue: [Why is my Vagrant bootstrap file not modifying bash_login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072132/why-is-my-vagrant-bootstrap-file-not-modifying-bash-login)

And more detail in my answer here: [Vagrant - Rails Not Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111177/vagrant-rails-not-installed/29986712#29986712)